# Disable the edit of ?id= in url jsf

Tags: security, jsf, url

before write the question sorry for my english. My question is this:

I have an web application in jsf, the application have new, edit and delete Categories, outgoings, Budgets, users, etc.

When open the edit page i have the url like this:

http://localhost:8080/Practica3/faces/usuarios/edit.xhtml?id=2

the problem is if the user change the number 2 for another number, and the another number exists in the dababase, the page change the data of the id 2 to the data of the new id.

The problem is if the id number X is of a data of another user, and the user that change the id is not in conditions to see that data.

How disable the edit of the id, or denied to show the data to the another user?

Thanks, and i hope have a response.

Comment: I wouldn't use a query string if you don't want the user to edit it. If the `id` is sensitive, it should at the very least be in the request body instead.

Comment: Totally not jsf related but basic web development. If you know who the user is, use its id in the query too and prevent reading other users records (multi-tenant is the right concept to use)

Comment: the id is in the url because in the index.xhtml the user press edit, and travel to edit.xhtml and have a converter, the converter read the id and fill the backing bean

Answer (score 0):

Just check in service layer if the current user is allowed to edit the requested entity. If not, then throw some security exception for which you could if necessary configure a custom error page in `web.xml`.

The technical problem has nothing to do with HTTP/JSF. If you "fix" it alone in JSF side, then you still have a gaping security hole in service layer which would affect any other frontend using it. The frontend is not responsible for business restrictions in service layer itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not stopping the editing of the ID.  That is on the client side/browser and you cannot stop this value from being edited.

You need to implement propery Access Security Controls.  When you get any response back, you need to check if the user can perform the action they specified (read, update, delete, etc.) as well as checking to make sure they have permission to the data they want to perform the action on.

These two topics are on the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10):

- [A4-Insecure Direct Object References](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References)
- [A7-Missing Function Level Access Control](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A7-Missing_Function_Level_Access_Control)

The pages will tell you what the problem is, mitigation stragegies, and different ways of testing for that in your application.

I would also become familiar with the other Top 10 categories (this is not an all inclusive list but a good starting point).